# Bibliography for a beginner in philosophy of language

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language

In my main time, I am a mathematician working in logic and category theory. As a logician, I am familiar with some bits of philosophy of language.

Stuff I have read:

- **Word and object**, *Quine*.
- **Naming and Necessity**, *Kripke*.
- **Tractatus logico-philosophicus**, *Wittgenstein*.

Several works in logic by *Tarski* and *Godel*, some works by *Lambek*. I have also a very gentle background in Lacanian psychoanalysis.

At this point in my studies, I feel I would like to attack my ignorance in the topic of **philosophy of language** with a more systematic and organized study, thus I would like to **gather a bibliography on the subject**. That's why I am here.

A couple of rules.

- Please, suggest me at least a manual, not just a collection of authors. I really feel like I am missing the *big picture*.
- If you suggest an author, please contextualize it, is it more of a philosopher, a linguist, maybe a mathematician?
- If you suggest an author, please consider to suggest an order to study the scientific production, should I read just everything? Parts of it?

I have seen that on this website someone asked [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/book-on-philosophy-of-language-for-beginners). Yet, I do not have the impression that it answers my question. My level is low indeed, but the OP makes clear that his/her level was even more basic than mine.

Comment: I'm have no interest in answering your question as you suggest, but I find it peculiar you have no references to the philosophy of language from the perspective of actual linguists. It's arguable that linguists know more about language than logicians. [Noam Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noam_Chomsky), is tremendously important in the field with his theory of generative grammar. You might also be interested in the the works of [George Lakoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Lakoff) and [Ray Jackendoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Jackendoff) who are cognitive linguists.

Comment: Sorry but this is a list question and isn't allowed here. You could consider checking the course outline for a philosophy subject at a university to see what books they recommend or require. And after reading a couple of introductory textbooks you'll then be in a position to know which directions of study you find interesting and what you want to read more about.

Comment: @curiousdannii, thanks. I did not know of this rule of the website. Feel free to close the question.

Comment: @JD I do not understand the meaning of your comment. I never claimed that what I have read is an exhaustive list, in fact I made quite precise that I claimed the opposite. It's just what I have read. Your suggestions are absolutely welcome.

Comment: My point is that it is arguable that the philosophy of language is best understood by the works of linguists who study language holistically rather than logicians who are largely interested in the logical aspect of it. Two more famous linguists are [Ferdinand de Saussure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_de_Saussure) and [Steven Pinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Pinker) who is a psycholinguist.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti There are also [introductory texts](https://books.google.com/books?id=5F_a2CwyH5YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Truth+and+Meaning:+An+Introduction+to+the+Philosophy+of+Language&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSiKSU5NjmAhUKHM0KHZhQAzEQ6AEwAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=Truth%20and%20Meaning%3A%20An%20Introduction%20to%20the%20Philosophy%20of%20Language&f=false).

Comment: See the other references in [this SE post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/current-philosophy-of-language).

Comment: Also [this one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/book-on-philosophy-of-language-for-beginners?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book on philosophy of language for beginners](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/book-on-philosophy-of-language-for-beginners)

Comment: It is a rather standard subject and in the Age of Wikipedia there is a ready answer: an article "Philosophy of Language" and also a category with 128 article, including Phphy of Lgg Literature. The name I would like to suggest is Roy Harris (1931-2015), a remarkable British linguist. His *Language Saussure and Wittgenstein* (1988) is a good place to get a view of the field.

Comment: There are some good anthologies that provide a suitable reading list as well as points to further literature. So you should start from there. There are two standard ones: Martinich / Sosa (eds). The Philosophy of Language. Oxford 2012. Ludlow (ed). Readings in the Philosophy of Language. Cambridge, Mass. 1997. There are tight interconnections between Phil. of language and semantics. For this you can consult Bob Carpenter. Type-Logical Semantics. Cambridge, Mass. 1997.